# ISP Blocking Internet access on Apple TV

Tags: appletv

My ISP is blocking Internet access on Apple TV's. How do they determine that traffic is originating from an Apple TV? Any way around it?

Comment: How have you determined that they are blocking AppleTV?

Comment: Blocking Apple tv’s specifically or video with the wrong region code embedded?

Comment: Their technical support told us.  There's a $50/month charge to be able to use the Apple TV on top of the normal service rate.

Comment: Then they are packet filtering (examining your traffic and dropping what looks to be related to Apple TV).  VPN would be your best bet.  What provider?  Is this US based?

Comment: TengoNet in Arizona

Comment: They seem to be a WiFi centric ISP that focuses on niche markets.  WiFi bandwidth get's saturated quickly and this tiered  pricing model ensures that bandwidth apps like Netflix and Apple TV don't over saturate the network.  Unfortunately, if you want it, you have to pay for it.

Comment: Use a VPN until you can find a different ISP. It ain't right to filter products like that but thanks to the net neutrality ruling this is the kind of thing we have to deal with!